# com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot

Tags: cocoa, launchd, nstask, xpc

In an `XCTestCase` test, I created a `NSTask` object and set it to run `printenv`. Then after the `NSTask` finished, I ran `printenv` using `fork` and `execv`. The output from both was identical except for one environment variable.

NSTask: `XPC_SERVICE_NAME=com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000004.Xcode`

execv: `XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0`

What is `com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot`?

Answer (score 2):

I posted this same question on Apple Support Communities and the gentleman that wrote the program called EtreCheck replied.

I think you will find your answer [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29316429):

> Hello TomsApple,
>
> I guess now you know some of the reasons behind that big disclaimer
>   that you saw when you ran EtreCheck.
>
> The "com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot" is just a method that Apple uses
>   to identify one of many categories of tasks that the system runs in
>   the background. I don't know how much background you have in UNIX, so
>   I don't know how much detail I should give you on this. In addition,
>   Apple doesn't document any of this, so at some point my answer would
>   move from fact to speculation.
>
> I can tell you that I added that "Other apps" section to EtreCheck
>   specifically to show some of the many different kinds of tasks that
>   the operating system is launching and running in the background.
>   Before, EtreCheck only looked at the 8 primary places to inject these
>   background tasks into the operating system. I knew I was missing one
>   of the paths for "login items" and wanted to capture that. I did
>   manage to capture that information, but I also collected a whole lot
>   more. I decided to keep them all in there, but hide the Apple tasks by
>   default. Even so, this "Other apps" section show how much more
>   complicated the operating system has become in the past few years. If
>   you want, you can run EtreCheck so that it doesn't hide Apple tasks
>   and doesn't hide known Apple failures. Just don't post that report
>   here on Apple Support Communities. It is a crazy-long list of
>   background tasks that are always running on your machine.
>
> Now I know this doesn't really answer your question. If you want more
>   specifics or more detail, I can provide it, but I can't necessarily
>   guarantee its accuracy. I have attempted to use my Apple Developer
>   Technical Support tickets to get more information about what some of
>   these things are and Apple refuses to answer.